# Call a function from function inside the same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to call a `function` from `another function`. And both of them defined inside the same `Controller`. But with everything I've tried so far it's `"funtion is not defined"` at the best. How to do this thing properly?

```
angular.module('App')

.controller('Controller', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

    this.getSomething1 = function() {};

    this.getSomething2 = function() {
        if (1 == 1) {
            getSomething1();
        }
    };
}]);
```

> ReferenceError: getSomething1 is not defined

Comment: I'm assuming you tried with `this.getSomething1();`? I usually define my functions on the `$scope` though.. `$scope.getSomething1 = function() { ... }` and just call it by `$scope.getSomething1();`.

Comment: @Arg0n, yes. And it gives me `TypeError: this.getSomething1 is not a function`

Comment: You should put other functions in a service, it's bad design to clutter controller methods with too much code

Comment: And instead of this I would bind it too $scope

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `this.getSomething1()` but there's a catch.

The problem here is that `this` inside the function is not always the same as `this` outside it. So to be safe, save the controller `this` in a variable and use that to call the function:

```
angular.module('App')

.controller('Controller', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getSomething1 = function () {
    };

    vm.getSomething2 = function ()  {
        if(1 == 1){
            vm.getSomething1();
        }
    };
}
]);
```

Another option that can make for much cleaner code is to always use named functions. You can still expose whichever of them need to be exposed on the controller but you can also call them directly.

```
angular.module('App')

.controller('Controller', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    angular.extend(this, { getSomething1: getSomething1, getSomething2: getSomething2 });
    return;

    function getSomething1() {
    };

    function getSomething2()  {
        if(1 == 1){
            getSomething1();
        }
    };
}
]);
```

This also has the benefit of separating the initialisation code at the top of the controller instead of scattering it through the function declarations.

The `extend` call looks even cleaner if you can use ES2016 syntax:

```
angular.extend(this, { getSomething1, getSomething2 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using the scope variable instead of this in the controllers,

```
angular.module('App')

.controller('Controller', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    var scope = $scope
    scope.getSomething1 = function () {
    };

    scope.getSomething2 = function ()  {
        if(1 == 1){
            scope.getSomething1();
        }
    };
}
]);
```

You can also declare a controller using a functional syntax as,

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('App')
    .controller('Controller', Controller);

  /** @ngInject */
    function Controller($http, $scope) {

        var scope = $scope
        scope.getSomething1 = function () {
        };

        scope.getSomething2 = function ()  {
            if(1 == 1){
                scope.getSomething1();
            }
        };
    }


})();
```

Comment: Much better though to use `this` and the "controller as" form of the syntax.

Comment: This would work but the named function approach sounds much better not only because it just works, it is cleaner as well. Adding the methods on scope will expose them to views (at least for the private one's).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope` instead of `this`

```
angular.module('App')

.controller('Controller', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

    $scope.getSomething1 = function() {};//<=== use of $scope

    this.getSomething2 = function() {
        if (1 == 1) {
            $scope.getSomething1(); //<=== use of $scope
        }
    };
}]);
```

That way, you can use the getSomething1 method in the controller (in js) and in your web page itself where you use your controller (in html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $scope instead of this.

```
angular.module('App')

.controller('Controller', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

    $scope.getSomething1 = function() {};

    $scope.getSomething2 = function() {
        if (1 == 1) {
            $scope.getSomething1();
        }
    };
}]);
```